Controlling fan with PWM signal from NE555
I designed a NE555 PWM regulator for a 12 V fan with sensing temperature from an NTC thermistor.
I would like to ask about the circuit for the output PWM signal from NE555. Because I have a 0-5 V PWM signal from NE555, I added MOSFET IRLIZ44N for switching the 12 V output PWM. I had to add the inverter in the circuit because when the PWM gate-source voltage is HIGH, the drain-source voltage is LOW which will stop the fan. The inverter in my opinion fixes this problem.
My question is this schematic gonna work or is there any problem with controlling the PWM signal for the fan? Is this MOSFET correct for this purpose?



Check your fan's datasheet; it may not require 12V on the PWM line. What is the value of R9 you intend to use? I hope not 1 ohm.

Does the fan comply with the Intel 4-wire PWM fan specs?

@AndrewMorton Yes

The spec (section 2.1.4) says the absolute maximum voltage for the PWM input signal is 5.25 V, so if it has had 12 V applied to it then the fan may be damaged. It would be a good idea to confirm that the PWM input on the fan works, if you've got something that uses that to control fan speed.

If motor's current is lower than MOSFET maximum current (30A according to datasheet; up to 15A is safe and with a heat sink), your circuit should work.
This transistor is already capable of operating with a low gate voltage  (logic-level gate driver). Assuming that you have 4V at 555's output pin, you can drive, practically, MOSFET's maximum current (see the figure below).

You can try another way to generate PWM signal, avoiding the inverter. Circuit below generates PWM signals that you can control through R1, R3, R4 and C1:

Try to simulate this circuit, varying mentioned resistors to obtain different duty cycles.
